# Why does the constructor array store null values except for one?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the objects from the constructor. so far all I get is one object and the remaining are all null. If someone can explain it to me so that a beginner can understand that would be much appreciated.

```
        Book catalogue[] = new Book[3];

        int select;
        do
        {
            select = bookMenu();
            switch(select)
            {
            case 1:  
                int i =0;
                if(catalogue[i] != null)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Test");
                    break;
                }
                catalogue[i] = addBook();
            case 2:     
                sortBook();     
            break;
            case 3:     
                searchBook(catalogue);   
            break;
            case 4:     
                displayBook(catalogue);  
            break;
            case 5:
            break;
            }   
        }
        while(select != 5);
    }
    public static int bookMenu()
    {
        int select;
        String menuOptions = "--Book store--\n"
                + "\n1. Add book to catalogue"
                + "\n2.Sort and display books by price"
                + "\n3. Search for a book by title" 
                + "\n4. Display all books"
                + "\n\n5. Exit";
        do
        {
            select = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menuOptions)); 
        }
        while(select < 1 || select > 5);
        return select;  
    }
    public static Book addBook()
    {
        int isbn;
        String title, author;
        Book catalogue = null;
        double price;
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        {   
            isbn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book ISBN or: "));
            title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book Title: ");
            author = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book Author: ");
            price = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Book Price: "));    
            catalogue = new Book(isbn, title, author, price);    
        }
        return catalogue;
    }
```

The display method brings up only the first last object and all else is null

```
public static void displayBook(Book catalogue[])//remain void
{
    String output = "";
    for(Book bk:catalogue)
    {
    output += bk + "\n";
    }        
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean something like `public static Book[] addBook()` ...

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please see how to create a [mcve]. The code is not the shorter and the problem not explain enough.

Comment: The `for` loop in `addBook` does nothing  but waste time.  Also `addBook` does not in fact _add_ a book to anything;  a better name would be `createBook`, which is more like what it actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case 1:  
    int i =0;
    if(catalogue[i] != null)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Test");
        break;
    }
    catalogue[i] = addBook();
```

Here you are initializing `i` with `0` in every call for adding the Book. So newly added book will be added on the first index only and gets overwritten by the new book.
So declare `i` globally and increment it after every successful addition.

You should change the variable name to some readable name so I suggest you to change it to `numberOfBooks` or `currentIndex`.

Comment: And change  the name from meaningless `i`, to something useful such as `numBooks`.

Comment: changing it globally didn't change anything

Comment: @KevinAnderson, Yup that should be done. Edited my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in your code here is how it is now

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Book[] catalogue = new Book[3];
    int i = 0;
    int select = 0;
    select = bookMenu();
    do {
        if (i == 3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Books added successfully");
            select = bookMenu();
        }
        switch (select) {
        case 1:
            catalogue[i++] = addBook();
            break;
        case 2:
            sortBook();
            break;
        case 3:
            searchBook(catalogue);
            break;
        case 4:
            displayBook(catalogue);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (select != 5 || i != 3);
}

public static int bookMenu() {
    int select;
    String menuOptions = "--Book store--\n" + "\n1. Add book to catalogue" + "\n2.Sort and display books by price"
            + "\n3. Search for a book by title" + "\n4. Display all books" + "\n\n5. Exit";
    do {
        select = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menuOptions));
    } while (select < 1 || select > 5);
    return select;
}

public static Book addBook() {
    int isbn;
    String title, author;
    double price;
    isbn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book ISBN or: "));
    title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book Title: ");
    author = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book Author: ");
    price = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book Price: "));
    return new Book(isbn, title, author, price);
}

public static void sortBook() {

}

public static void searchBook(Book catalogue[])// remain void
{
    String searchValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the title of the book you are searching for");
    boolean found = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.length && catalogue[i] != null; i++) {
        if (searchValue.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogue[i].getTitle())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book details: " + catalogue[i].toString());
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The title does not exist in the collection ");
    }
}

public static void displayBook(Book[] catalogue)// remain void
{
    String output = "";
    for (Book bk : catalogue) {
        output += bk + "\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
}
```

}

And here is your Book.java

```
public class Book {
private int isbn;
private String author;
private String title;
private double price;

/**
 * 
 */
public Book(int isbn, String author, String title, double price) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Book [isbn=" + isbn + ", author=" + author + ", title=" + title + ", price=" + price + "]";
}
```

}

Now let me explain what we were missing here.
First of all the local variable "i" was being reinitialized every time, so moved that out side of the do while loop.
secondly in your addBook method, you were iterating through a for loop three times where you were expecting the input from the user but not storing those things anywhere and the Book object was being returned from the addBook method only for the inputs fetched for the third time.
Additionaly i did some changes in your while condition so that the code works properly when you run it.
Also implement toString method in Book class so that you get to see the values when displayBook method renders the array.

Comment: Thanks, dude, I looked over the code and found these errors based on what everyone was telling me. thanks again for all your help.